# Router.navigate not loading the full page content in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I am trying to fix an issue users are having after impersonating as a different user in the system. Currently, a regional user could impersonate as someone else which does not load the full content of the page as they now have to press F5 to see everything on this page. I tried to reproduce this issue by pointing to the same database in local but not able to do so. When I go to the DEV url for instance, I then try impersonating as a different user which then loads the page partially and refreshing the page (F5), I see the entire content. I believe this is happening due to the route navigate, not sure if I am missing anything to pass in this function.

```
this.router.navigate(['/', user.Company.Abbreviation.toLowerCase()]);
```

This is the full function that the Impersonate button is executing.

```
setImpersonatation() {
this.store.dispatch(new AuditSearchClearAction());
this.store.dispatch(new CompanyChangedAction(this.impersonationForm.value.company, null));

const user = this.impersonationForm.value.user as UserLogin;
this.store.dispatch(new BaseUserSetAction(user as User));
this.store.dispatch(new AuthorizeAction(user));
this.router.navigate(['/', user.Company.Abbreviation.toLowerCase()]);
this.store.dispatch(new MyWorkSetLetterReminderUserAction(user.UserId));
```

}

When I switch a user, I get the screen below.
[image]

But when I refresh the page (F5), then i see the entire data.
[image]

Do I need to add any parameters to the router.navigate so it loads the page correctly? Seems like something is missing of when trying to load the page after the Impersonate button is clicked.
Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
setImpersonatation() {
this.store.dispatch(new AuditSearchClearAction());
this.store.dispatch(new CompanyChangedAction(this.impersonationForm.value.company, null));

const user = this.impersonationForm.value.user as UserLogin;
this.store.dispatch(new BaseUserSetAction(user as User));
this.store.dispatch(new AuthorizeAction(user));
this.store.dispatch(new MyWorkSetLetterReminderUserAction(user.UserId));
**this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
this.router.navigate(['/', user.Company.Abbreviation.toLowerCase()]);**
```

}

Comment: Is this API call inside in ngOnInit?. is this component is already loaded when you switch the URL ?

Comment: Your store is syncronize with localstorage or somthing else? if it is not synchronized, it could be because your store is emptied when you press F5

Comment: Hi sojin, I don't see the API call on the ngOnInit. There is a separate call to load the MyWork and Letters Reminders that is done through an event on the page.

Comment: Hey Den, sorry new to Angular. Could you elaborate on what do you mean by the store is emptied when we press F5. Could I try adding replaceUrl: true on the router.navigate to force the page to reload like we do with F5? Since I am not able to reproduce this in local, I would have to push the code to the DEV env to actually test to see if this works.

Comment: Try: 1. Put the router navigate at the very bottom of the method. 2. Use change detector ref to detect changes in the page (maybe after dispatch). 3. Check dev server config files. I personally think is because you need to use change detector ref

Comment: Hi Callan, Are you referring to something like import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';  And add this line this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); right after this.store.dispatch(new MyWorkSetLetterReminderUserAction(user.UserId)); ?

Comment: @Callan I have edited the post above by adding a UPDATE section moving the lines as you have suggested. Let me know if thats what you were referring to. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is right. Is the data available in the TS file but not in the html? Like if you console log the data on click, is it available?

Comment: @bladerunner could you show the code where you set up the data-source for what you're displaying here? And maybe what your ngrx effects and resolvers look like (just the ones relevant to your dispatched actions)? Those are the culprits that come to mind for me

Answer (score 2):

Using a resolver is always a good choice in cases that data is not ready to generate the page UI.
Resolver is preventing your app from navigate unless the data is fetched completely from server.

Steps:

1. create a resolver service by running this command:

```
ng generate resolver test-resolver
```

2. you have to put your ajax call in the resolve method of resolver:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TestResolver implements Resolve<Hero> {
  constructor(private service: TestService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return this.service.testAjax();
  }
}
```

3. you have to define your resolver in your routing module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'test',
        component: TestComponent,
        resolve: {
          test: TestResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

4. you have to catch the response in your component (in this case TestComponent):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: ``
})
export class TestComponent {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data.test);
    });
  }
}
```

In this way you will navigate to the next page ONLY if data is fully loaded and this feature makes it so much easier to implement a better user experience like a loading on navigation to those pages that require some data to be fetched.

Comment: I may just not be familiar with the proper use of resolvers, but in my experience, it seemed like resolvers would add too much "blocking" to the app. It feels as it they were designed with promises in mind and then observables came later and provided a more async solution. The rest of the page can load, but it gets updated the the observable emits a new value. But I'd love it if you could enlighten me on a proper use-case where resolvers are less blocking! (honestly, no sarcasm intended)

Comment: routing may be a little slow bot resolvers impacts UX alot and gives user much better experience. resolvers are very suitable where opening a page without a specific data is useless and user has to wait until data is loaded. I hope this to be useful and descriptive for you. @acat

Comment: thanks! it seems so obvious now! that was really very helpful!